# sign html file password protected

Tags: c#, file-io, password-protection, chilkat

i have HTML file which is password protected and i am signing using (chilkat) that is third party tool.
the problem is that it neither get sign nor giving me any error.
how i will identify in my code that file require password

here is my code

```
           if (!pcSourceFile.EndsWith(".pdf"))
            {
                byte[] lcReadByte = null;
                pSerialNumber = locertTest.SerialNumber;
                Issuer = locertTest.IssuerCN;
                SignTime = DateTime.Now;
                loCryptoTest.SetSigningCert(locertTest);
                byte[] lcWriteBytes = null;
                lcReadByte = loCryptoTest.ReadFile(pcSourceFile);
                //lcWriteBytes = loCryptoTest.OpaqueSignBytes(lcReadByte);
                lcWriteBytes = loCryptoTest.OpaqueSignBytes(lcReadByte);

                if (lcWriteBytes.Length == 0)
                {

   GlobalStatic.WriteLog(loCryptoTest.LastErrorText, "Opeque Sig nature Error", "Signature");
                    return false;
                }

                loCryptoTest.WriteFile(pcDestFile, lcWriteBytes);
                lcReadByte = null;
                lcWriteBytes = null;

            }
```

Comment: HTML or PDF? What's `loCryptoTest` - a chilkat object? You'll probably have to ask their support for an API to test if the PDF is password protected, and a explanation why their object isn't working.

Comment: Chilkat.Crypt2 loCryptoTest; html file

Comment: i have HTML file if its password protected how i will come to know in C#

Comment: I still don't understand sorry. There's no such thing as a password-protected HTML file I don't think - at least no standard built into HTML, unless it's really XHTML and you're using one of the XML encryption formats? - and your code sample says `.EndsWith(".pdf")` which is confusing me. Unless you mean you're reading the source over HTTP from a web page that is give you an authorisation error in response? Is that read happening in Chilkat code? It still sounds to me like you'll need to talk to them.

Comment: its ok thank you so much for your time to reply me i will go with your suggestion , that i will talk to support team of chilkat